# Can dynamic type in Dart 2 assign to several value of difference type?

Tags: dynamic, dart, type-inference, dart-2

Can dynamic type in Dart 2 assign to value of difference type and how compile infer them?

For example what is x type in dart 2 and does this compile?

```
dynamic x = 1;
x = x + "Hello";
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `dynamic` type is special. It really means "trust me, I know what I'm doing" and it turns off some static type checking.

As a type constraint, `dynamic` is really equivalent to `Object` (you can assign any value to a variable with type `dynamic`), but when you try to call methods on the object, you are allowed to *try*, even if the method doesn't exist on `Object`.

In this case, `dynamic x = 1;` works because `1` is assignable to `Object`.
Line 2 fails. `x = x + "Hello";` *tries* to call the `+` method on `1` with `"Hello"` as argument, and even though the `+` operator exists, the argument has the wrong type.

You said "trust me, I know what I'm doing", so the compiler let you do try - there are no static warnings or errors. You got they type wrong, so the runtime stops you before things become unsound.
You could also have written `x.argleBargleGlopGlyf(42)`, and the compiler still wouldn't have stopped you, even if there is no `argleBargleGlopGlyf` method anywhere in your program. With great static power comes great dynamic responsibility.

Answer (score 3):

In Dart 2, `dynamic` is a special type signature - sort of denoting *anything*.

In your above example, `x` is `dynamic`. At runtime on line 1, it will be an int. So if you write `print(x is int)`, it will be `true`. However, statically, it is `dynamic`. You won't get code-completion (try typing `x.` in an IDE.

The next line will be a *runtime* error (versus a static error if it was typed properly).

In my experience, with Dart 2, you'll rarely use the `dynamic` keyword.